# Basic application of Cauchy's Integral Theorem

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

My book (Saff/Snider, page 195) say:

> The integral $$\int_{|z| = 2} \frac{e^z}{z^2 - 9} = 0$$
>
> because of the Cauchy theorem since $\frac{e^z}{z^2 - 9}$ is analytic  everywhere except $z = \pm 3.$ And since these points lie outside $|z| = 2$, it is $0$ by the theorem.

Q1: The domain of $\frac{e^z}{z^2 - 9}$ is $D = C-\{\pm 3\}$ and is not simply connected, how are they applying the theorem?

Q2: If I am looking at this in the real case, it is not even continuous on $D = C-\{\pm 3\}$. I am guessing analytic in the Cauchy-Riemann sense that it requires local analyticity (at a point) as opposed to the whole domain?

Note: I am not referring to the Cauchy integral formula. I am referring to the first one everyone learns ($f \in H(D) \implies \int_C f = 0$)

Comment: Do you have a statement of the theorem somewhere?

Comment: Basically if $f$ is analytic in a simply connected domain and $\gamma$ is a closed contour in $D$, then $\int_Gamma f = $

Comment: $B(0,{5 \over 2})$ is simply connected and the integrand is analytic there. I'm not sure what you mean by the real case. The reals are a different world.

Comment: Oh wow I just realized this is equivalent to integrating over points that are out of the question like in the real case.

Comment: I think in my head I thought this was $\int_D f$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hypothesis is that the path of integration is contained in a simply-connected region in which the function is analytic, and this clearly holds in the case in question.

Comment: Is there a quick way to remember the theorem without the proof? Because the proof is very routine mechanical work.

Comment: I don't know. It's easy to remember it's something about an integral being zero, and if you remember the residue theorem then you know that the integrand has to be analytic inside the path of integration.

Answer (score 0):

Your function $$\frac{e^z}{z^2 - 9}$$ is entire on $$|Z|\le 2.5$$ which which includes the curve $$|Z|=2$$ completely.

Thus you may apply the Cauchy integral theorem and get the answer of $0$